# How do I let the user choose a location in Google Maps and return the chosen point to my App Inventor application?

Tags: android, android-intent, latitude-longitude, google-maps-android-api-2, app-inventor

I am developing an app using App Inventor.
It includes the need for a user to press a button - to save a location when they are at the location.
But every time this is not practical. So I want to implement a method in my App Inventor app which will:
-Open Google Maps
-Let the user select any point on the map with no additional info.
-After choosing, return to the app and return latitude, longitude values for the location that is selected.
This is really important for me, help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Using Google Map Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android). See the `Getting the Location that was touched` part.

Comment: @SamRad, that was useful but any idea how that could be implemented within my App Inventor app and not using the 'coding' part using IDE but using MIT AI?

Comment: I have no idea what _AppInventor_ is. But it seems like you can't use any Java in your application since `App Inventor does not generate Java source code.` You should find another way I guess. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example **How to get coordinates for any Location on Google Maps back to App Inventor** here: http://puravidaapps.com/coordinates.php
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the most clear answer i've got for this question until now..
i got my API key, read this part from the link you provided : "Then use your API key for your queries to the Google Maps API inside the embedded HTML/Javascript document."
where do i use the API key in my application?
can you please clear that?

Comment: where is the maps.html file?

Comment: The API key needs to be stored inside the embedded HTML/JavaScript file. The html file is stored as asset inside the app and this file does all the "work" ;-)