# Cannot get the coordinates of location using App Inventor

Tags: android, google-maps, location, app-inventor

I am making an app in App Inventor that requires location of the user. However, sometimes location is shown as *longitude=0*, *latitude=0* and *No address is available*. I don't know why it's working at some locations and not at all the locations.

[Get Altitude in App Inventor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440823/get-altitude-in-app-inventor)

I have tried the suggestions given in the above link, but no use.

[image]

Finally, I have decided to get the coordinates from the map. For that I have tried the instructions given in the below link.

[How do I let the user choose a location in Google Maps and return the chosen point to my App Inventor application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010598/how-do-i-let-the-user-choose-a-location-in-google-maps-and-return-the-chosen-poi)

Here, although I got the API, I don't know where to insert that key. I also don't have any source from the HTML page mentioned by user Taifun. Could any one please help me.

[image]
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: see [SteveJG's answer in the forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/Lj1COFDc1Y4/VNmQSeI3j5gJ) and concerning my [coordinates example](https://puravidaapps.com/coordinates.php) see the green box on the bottom of that page.

Comment: Thanks Taifun. I found the html code here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292395/getting-app-inventor-2-variable-values-in-an-html-javascript-file)